# PHP - PDO mysql backup to remote host?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Welcome,

How can i create a full backup of my database (all tables inside) to remote mysql server using PHP PDO ?

Is there any easy way ?

Comment: Why do you need to use PHP for such a task? Is there no shell access to your MySQL server you could use?

Comment: There may be legitimate uses for this. The most important I can think of is platform independence. If you write software to be deployed on a multitude of systems, this may reduce support costs (if it works of course). But I agree, if you're talking about a single system, use a tool specifically written for this purpose. It's faster, reliable and well-tested.

Comment: Yes, I need full platform independence. I need that application for several websites. Some servers don't have shell_exec enabled, some work in safemode, basedir. I know i should use mysql dump but it's impossible. I get idea to create account for every website into my mysql server and "synchronize" user database with my. I know that mysql via internet isn't fast but for backup... look like perfect solutions. Replication isn't possible because end user won't have right to create databases.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the [MySQL documentation on replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html). I would not recommend doing this with PHP and PDO. You'll have better results when you use the right tool for the job. IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to perform a `SELECT * FROM [table]` on every table you have in your source database, then run a big transaction on your destination database that deletes all previous table data and then inserts the new data.
Basically something similar to this snippet:

```
<?php
// $srcDB and $destDB are instances of PDO.
// $tableNames is an array of tables in the correct order.
//
//   $srcDB = new PDO(...);
//   $destDB = new PDO(...);
//   $tableNames = array('table1', 'table2');

$srcDB->beginTransaction();
$destDB->beginTransaction();

try {
    foreach ($tableNames as $tableName) {
        // Fetch records from source
        $srcStatement = $srcDB->query('SELECT * FROM '.$tableName);
        $rows = $srcStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        // Free resources allocated by query
        $srcStatement->closeCursor();
        $srcStatement = null;

        if ( count($rows) === 0 )
            continue; // No rows

        // Prepare records to insert
        $insertValues = array();
        foreach ($rows as $row)
            $insertValues[] = '('.implode(',', array_map(array($destDB, 'quote'), $row)).')';

        // Clear destination table      
        if ( $destDB->exec('DELETE FROM '.$tableName) === false )
            throw new Exception('DELETE failed for table '.$tableName);

        // Write records
        if ( $destDB->exec('INSERT INTO '.$tableName.' VALUES '.implode(',', $insertValues)) === false )
            throw new Exception('INSERT failed for table '.$tableName);
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $srcDB->rollBack();
    $destDB->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}

$result = $destDB->commit();
$srcDB->rollBack(); // or $srcDB->commit() - we did not change the source DB though

if ( !$result )
    throw new Exception('Commit failed');

// Success
?>
```

Notes:

- At least for MySQL, quoting INTs (e.g. primary key IDs) causes no errors and works properly, so `$destDB->quote()` in the `array_map()` should be safe then, but I don't know for sure if this applies for all data types and all database systems.
- Doing everything in a single transaction prevents inconsistent backups.
- The example assumes that you have the same database structure in both databases, with all columns appearing in **exactly the same order**.
- Your tables have to be deleted and built in correct order to not violate any **foreign key constraints**, otherwise the backup could fail.
- **Test extensively** (ideally on a dedicated test system with a copy of your live data) with different scenarios (some or all tables empty, tables with lots of rows, all tables non-empty etc.) to ensure that it works reliably and that your backup script does not run out of memory due to a low [memory_limit setting](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)). Compare the destination database with the source by dumping them e.g. with `mysqldump` or the like to verify that they are identical and that the backup is complete. You might even encounter nasty PDO bugs in the worst case that you may need to work around – Google and SO are your friends :-).

**EDIT:**
One could additionally use the special [INFORMATION_SCHEMA database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html) to query the table names and determine the foreign key dependencies automatically.
Also, you might want to [disable foreign key checks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) on the target database during transfer (and reenable them afterwards) when you have self-referential foreign key relations to prevent failures due to constraint violations.

Answer (score 0):

If it's about having a backup, you should really stick to established admin tools. Use SQLBuddy or PHPMySQLAdmin.

You could write a duplication system using a RPC method or data transfer with JSON or something. But that needs securing, would be slow and only helpful for content transfer, not SQL schema replication.